# there is a product in shopping cart but Mini cart is not displaying the product

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7

[![i had 2 product in shopping but mini cart is not displaying the product.
I had done all the checkout setting in sales, but nothing is working/.][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BMwa.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BMwa.png)